# Win 10 PC ethernet cable stuck in "unplugged" and "identifying" loop

Tags: networking, ethernet, drivers, cable

I have a PC that has problems connecting to the internet via cable. The ethernet adapter is stuck in a loop of "cable unplugged" "identifying" "unknown network" and back to "cable unplugged". After random amount of times of the loop, it successfully connects to the internet. Sometimes 10min, sometimes 1 hour. 
Video of it: https://vimeo.com/313365533?

I have tried so far:

- Verified that **cable** and **router** are not the problems. Same setup works on other machine.
- Tried uninstalling, reinstalling, updating, enabling and disabling the Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller driver in various forms
- Changed the "Speed and Duplex" from **Auto Negation** to **"100MBps Full Duplex"**. I also tried all the other forms. But this one made the loop *faster* so to speak.
- IPConfig shows only "Media Disconnected"

I have looked at similar questions and none have provided a solution for it for me. I have 50/50 mbps connection coming in through the cable, not sure if that's related. I have a CAT5+ cable that should support up to 100Mpbs. Regardless this started happening randomly after the PC crashed yesterday. (Literally closed down). Maybe it shorted something somewhere and the hardware has now become faulty? How can I make sure?

Best regards

Comment: Regarding your 3rd point, disabling autonegotiation will only make things worse (unless it's changed identically on both ends of the cable). Most Ethernet devices, if they don't receive an autonegotiation signal, will use the slowest 10M/Half mode.

Comment: `Verified that cable and router are not the problems` - How did you verify that? Also, have you replaced the network adapter?

Comment: I have tested the cable coming from the router on other machines and it works just fine. What's weird is that after X amounts of retries, it gets and stays connected until next reboot/hibernate. I have not replaced the adapter yet. Leaving that as a last resort. @joeqwerty

Comment: Why would you leave replacing the adapter as a last resort? You've looked at all of the obvious causes except the adapter. What are you going to do, keep chasing a ghost? Replace the adapter and see if that resolves the problem. With network problems you should always troubleshoot from the physical layer up, that means replacing the adapter. Only by doing that can you rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you've ruled out a broken cable, it most likely is the NIC. Either the hardware is bad (anything from bent pins in the 8P8C jack to chip failure) or the driver is.

Assuming it's an onboard NIC, deactivate in BIOS and fit a PCIe card.

> Changed the "Speed and Duplex" from Auto Negation to "100MBps Full Duplex". I also tried all the other forms. But this one made the loop faster so to speak.

You've just broken autonegotiation. Unless you set both ends' ports to the exact same settings, the other end probably autodetects the link speed but without autoneg it falls back to half duplex, creating a duplex mismatch.